# Breaklines in QGIS interpolation plugin

Tags: qgis, interpolation, breaklines

How can I prepare data to generate a DTM using points and breaklines, but where every breakline has nodes at different heights. For example, a river valley, which regularly falls,  or a dorsal line, where each vertex is a different height.

Thanks for the answer. Tom

Answer (score 2):

From my point of view, break lines are lines with very different values on each sides (e.g. cliffs), so I would not consider a river as a break line.

I would suggest that you use a TIN interpolation, with your lines used as "structure lines" and checking the "use Z coordinates" (assuming your lines have Z values)

Note : I assume that you use the Interpolation plugin

Comment: That's what I'm talkimg about! No rivers or clifs has equals altitude along structural lines. I'll be testing that option "use Z coordinates" soon. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I think that the default behavior for breaklines is that they do follow a valley bottom, or ridgeline. See this for example: https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/extensions/3d-analyst/breaklines-in-surface-modeling.htm

What you're asking is that a line can include specific height values on each vertex along the line, and I don't know of any GIS products that do this. You'd need points at each vertex, and a line as a breakline that follows these vertices, I reckon.

Comment: Broken link....

Comment: Fixed the broken link

Answer (score -1):

Consider convert those lines to points, then run the interpolation.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! As a new user please take the [tour] to learn about our focused Q&A format.  A good answer should include an explanation as to how to perform the steps in your answer, and what they do to solve the problem.  Please [edit] your answer to include more detailed information.